# PyCharm не видит папку venv при добавлении нового interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, venv

Пишу код для бекэнда на фраймворке *Django* и столкнулся с такой проблемой: при создании нового  виртуального окружения в **PyCharm**, папка venv сразу добавляется в **Exclude files**, затем я убираю ее с Exclude, но PyCharm все равно ее не видит (не отображается в терминале). Пробовал использовать `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`, но это не помогает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну так  у вас же прямо написано no interpreter. Выберите нужный питон.

Comment: такая же беда, если решили буду благодарен за подсказку